# Updated from 1.12 to 1.13 now everything I did in my game is gone

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So today I was very excited to open my world with 1.13 and, as prompted, I clicked to back up my world. However, when I got into my game, I realized very quickly that literally EVERYTHING was gone. My boats, all my builds, my farm, everything that wasn't in my direct inventory has basically been reset to back when I first started the game. I've been playing for a long time and I have done A LOT. Is there any way to bring my stuff back? Do I have to start all over? Please help, I am so sad.

Comment: The only reason that popup to backup is there is because they forgot to remove it when going from the snapshot phase to the release phase. Lucky for you! So now you have a backup, right? Just restore that.

Comment: Can you attach or upload and link the world backup, please? I'll try to reproduce it. And if it is reproducible, it will certainly get fixed soon, because that's a really bad bug.

Comment: Is this a hosted Minecraft world, or was it a locally stored world?

Comment: Have you looked in the save folder to see if anything is there?

Answer (score 1):

You **backed-up** *your* world right? So hold down the "Windows" key and press "R". A dialog box will pop-up, and your going to type in "**%appdata%**", then press the *Enter* key.

You **should** see a folder named "*.minecraft*" at the *very* *top*. Your going to open that folder and find a folder called "*backups*" open that folder and then find the name of your world.

Copy that .zip folder into your "saves" folder and extract the files. Delete the remaining .zip file and your good to go!